Why are aggregated assets not working in this specific setup?
Since migrating to Drupal 10.4 (from 9.5.11), the aggregate CSS/JS files option is not working anymore.
When I look at the source of the page, I can see the links to the assets:
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_2h_IsPmKRnfJEoffJE7HjEejI_E9myH2gQ4_lq3lHYM.css?delta=1&amp;language=fr&amp;theme=umami&amp;include=eJx9kF1uxDAIhC8Ux2cimGbRYojA3p-evtl0U2kf3BfLfDMa7EHTRo_WQXLxvoHM-EeSsF5jwv8szUwW8N3klNHqZkraYu4VKqe0gCqNVQctrOtIR_Ay0goHCnAdp3-ZNfK0iOF15LkQlHGC72qqu_ZrUPMKwt80xcW8YW9nIec8xTMa1bxA0PSuJp8VHaF5f3TEcz4cH0StnGQVW0DegxPyRglNhLCxaUw9yM_Vr_vM-MI3pnvk45yrlS70gZxi_1_wjdLqXH4ArTvDUA" />

<script src="/sites/default/files/js/js_wTnHpx-ZkSP5xd2Jd_UxaJZ9RJUkBOoz6MIYQkULl7M.js?scope=header&amp;delta=0&amp;language=fr&amp;theme=umami&amp;include=eJx9jFsOQiEMRDd0gTW4ElNgoo3QNlCMy9cYjIkf_s3rTObL2diQ8hZHUXE8fFFLdSyjFr9JaCy3-X_iqi3TeI0GUtFuKhCfcXXqHMIVVLHbDVNxvuP9fWw6fV5-fMQsZDjVzvIE5FdIyQ"></script>

But when I open these links, they return the generic 404 Not Found and file are not generated in the folder.
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8080

I have tried with a new install (on the umami demo), it's not working either.
The issue seems to be with the .htaccess file, that is automatically created in the assets directory (file_assets_path = sites/default/files), that prevents the CSS and JS generation.
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

When I remove this file, I can open the link previously mentionned, it generates and returns the JS/CSS asset, and the file can be seen in the folder.
But eventually, the .htaccess file is created again. I have also tried to change the file_assets_path in another location than the file_public_path, not working either.
Tested on both of these environments :

PHP 8.1.19, Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
PHP 8.3.14, Apache/2.4.62 (Debian)

Can anybody help me with that. Thank you

I've looked at release notes; the only thing related I've seen is https://www.drupal.org/node/3301716 which describes how it works exactly the way I thought it would. The changes about the API shouldn't apply to my case, since I just use the demo configuration.

There was a major change to the assets system back in 10.1 which caused some issues when people upgraded a few years ago.

It's possibly https://www.drupal.org/node/2888767 or https://www.drupal.org/node/3301716. Those are only the change records, but there were some bug and support issues opened around that time in the assets subsystem: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=asset%20library%20system&order=created&sort=desc.
